# Groovy exception when starting web app

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy

My application was running properly and since i restarted the app its all broken . i got the current error:

> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.exceptions.GroovyPagesException: Error applying layout : main
>   Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag : Module [jquery] depends on resource [/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js] but the file cannot be found

The problem is that the jquery plugin works fine before this restart and i didn't change anything . Any idea on why the problem occured and how to resolve it ?

for your information, i am running the app using esigate and jetty

thx in advance

Comment: you have to add tag [grails]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `application.js` page in directory `\grails-app\assets\javascripts\application.js` that there is `jquery-1.8.3.min.js` included or not. And your `jquery-1.8.3.min.js` exits on `grails-app\assets\javascripts` folder.